# PHP - The fastest way to get content of another website and parse this content

Tags: php, curl, optimization, web-crawler, urlfetch

I have to get a few params of user's from website. I can do it because every user have an unique ID and I can search users by URL:

> http://page.com/search_user.php?uid=**X**

So I added this URL in for() loop and I tried to get 500 results:

```
<?php

$start = time();
$results = array();

for($i=0; $i<= 500; $i++)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://page.com/search_user.php?uid='.$i);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 desktopsmiley_2_2_5643778701369665_44_71 DS_gamingharbor Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $p = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ( preg_match('"<span class=\"uname\">(.*?)</span>"si', $p, $matches) )
    {
        $username = $matches[1];
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }

    preg_match('"<table cellspacing=\"0\">(.*?)</table>"si', $p, $matches);
    $comments = $matches[1];

    preg_match('"<tr class=\"pos\">(.*?)</tr>"si', $comments, $matches_pos);
    preg_match_all('"<td>([0-9]+)</td>"si', $matches_pos[1], $matches);
    $comments_pos = $matches[1][2];

    preg_match('"<tr class=\"neu\">(.*?)</tr>"si', $comments, $matches_neu);
    preg_match_all('"<td>([0-9]+)</td>"si', $matches_neu[1], $matches);
    $comments_neu = $matches[1][2];

    preg_match('"<tr class=\"neg\">(.*?)</tr>"si', $comments, $matches_neg);
    preg_match_all('"<td>([0-9]+)</td>"si', $matches_neg[1], $matches);
    $comments_neg = $matches[1][2];

    $comments_all = $comments_pos+$comments_neu+$comments_neg;

    $about_me = 0;
    if ( preg_match('"<span>O mnie</span>"si', $p) )
    {
        $about_me = 1;
    }

    $results[] = array('comments' => $comments_all, 'about_me' => $about_me, 'username' => $username);
}

echo 'Generated in: <b>'.(time()-$start).'</b> seconds.<br><br>';
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Finally I got results:
- everything was generated in 135 seconds.

Then I I replaced curl with **file_get_contents()** and I got: 155 seconds.

Is faster way to get this results than curl ?? I have to get 20.000.000 results from another page and 135 seconds is too much for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a daily occurrence or is this just a one off?

Comment: One off. Finally I would like to start this script using CRON and get all results (20.000.000) in time parts (1 second break for 500 results)..

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to query different URLs 500 times, maybe you should consider asynchronous approach. The problem with above is that the slowest part (bottleneck) are the curl requests themselves. While waiting for the response, your code is doing nothing.

Try to have a look at [PHP asynchronous cURL with callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26039848/1168156) (i.e. you would make 500 requests "almost at once" and process responses as they come - asynchronously).

Comment: So I should create an array with 500 URLs and then in callback function create preg_match'es based on response from this callback ?

Comment: @NewbieUser Sorry, I don't have time to write the complete solution for you, I'm just trying to point out that the most promising way seems to be to parse / process the fetched URL in some callback asynchronously, so that the execution is not like: fetch, wait, response, parse/process, fetch another one, wait ... but something like fetch1, fetch2, fetch3, response1, parse1, fetch4, response2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a previous answer of mine regarding how to divide and conquer this kind of job.

[debugging long running PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511365/debugging-long-running-php-script/31566312#31566312)

In your case I'd say you follow the same idea, but you'd further chunk the requests into groups of 500, say.